# php function to sum values from multi dimensional array

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array, sum

My $results array looks like this..

```
$results = [
    '2020-09-06' => [
        'Etsy' => ['total_orders' => 2, 'total_stickers' => 3, 'total_value' => 7.8300000000000001],
        'Woo' => ['total_orders' => 10, 'total_stickers' => 20, 'total_value' => 100.38],
        'eBay' => ['total_orders' => 17, 'total_stickers' => 18, 'total_value' => 67.359999999999999],
    ],
    '2020-09-07' => [
        'Etsy' => ['total_stickers' => 8, 'total_orders' => 4, 'total_value' => 34.920000000000002],
        'Woo' => ['total_stickers' => 9, 'total_orders' => 3, 'total_value' => '52.90'],
        'eBay' => ['total_stickers' => 23, 'total_orders' => 21, 'total_value' => 58.030000000000001],
    ]
];
```

I want to echo the combined sum for each individual item (total_value, total_stickers, total_orders) for each "marketplace" by date and thought i could do this if i pass the variables in a function and tried the following..

```
$array_value_sum = create_function('$array,$key', '$total = 0; foreach($array as $row) $total = $total + $row[$key]; return $total;');
echo "Total Current Value" . $array_value_sum($obj['results'], 'total_value');
```

That way I can change the variables and sum any of them with a similar echo line but this is not working for me, do I also need to specify dates in a foreach? or how can I achieve this expected output..

```
Array
(
    [2020-09-06] => Array
        (
                    [total_orders] => 29
                    [total_stickers] => 41
                    [total_value] => 175.5      
        )
    [2020-09-07] => Array
        (           
                    [total_stickers] => 40
                    [total_orders] => 28
                    [total_value] => 145.85
        )
)
```

Comment: tip its better for us if you use an array instead of a print_r, feel free to use [this tool](https://print-r-converter-199219.appspot.com/) to convert it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks, updated.

Comment: np, do you have an expected output? as can tweak my answer if it does not fit what you want

Comment: @LawrenceCherone just added an expected output.

Comment: also be careful of the floats, ie. https://3v4l.org/nHoUU (though tbh nothing costs nano cents unless its bitcoin but that only goes to 8)

Comment: Why are you still using `create_function()`? PHP has had anonymous functions since 5.3, and `create_function` is deprecated in 7.2.

Comment: @Barmar because truthfully I only a tiny bit understand what I'm doing and got this far with copy/paste/edit try again, does it work yet, yes = great, no = more research and trial and error till it does what Im trying to do, I've no idea if the code I'm using from examples is old/out of date/been updated etc :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, no need to over-engineer, if you know the structure, just iterate trough the values, and sum them up, this is how I would do that.

This way you can add many other marketplace and dates without later modifying the code.

```
<?php
$results = [
    '2020-09-06' => [
        'Etsy' => ['total_orders' => 2, 'total_stickers' => 3, 'total_value' => 7.8300000000000001],
        'Woo' => ['total_orders' => 10, 'total_stickers' => 20, 'total_value' => 100.38],
        'eBay' => ['total_orders' => 17, 'total_stickers' => 18, 'total_value' => 67.359999999999999],
    ],
    '2020-09-07' => [
        'Etsy' => ['total_stickers' => 8, 'total_orders' => 4, 'total_value' => 34.920000000000002],
        'Woo' => ['total_stickers' => 9, 'total_orders' => 3, 'total_value' => '52.90'],
        'eBay' => ['total_stickers' => 23, 'total_orders' => 21, 'total_value' => 58.030000000000001],
    ]
];

$total = ['total_stickers' => 0, 'total_orders' => 0, 'total_value' => 0];

foreach ($results as $k => $v){
  foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1){
   $total['total_stickers'] += $v1['total_stickers'];
   $total['total_orders'] += $v1['total_orders'];
   $total['total_value'] += $v1['total_value'];
  
  }
}

var_dump($total);
/*
 * array(3) {
  ["total_stickers"]=>
  int(81)
  ["total_orders"]=>
  int(57)
  ["total_value"]=>
  float(321.42)
}
* */
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to simply loop over it with a couple of foreach's and add the values together.

Sum all by date, including all marketplaces.

```
<?php
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $date => $marketplaces) {
    foreach ($marketplaces as $data) {
        if (!isset($result[$date])) $result[$date] = ['total_orders' => 0, 'total_stickers' => 0, 'total_value' => 0];
        
        $result[$date] = [
            'total_stickers' => $result[$date]['total_stickers'] + $data['total_stickers'],
            'total_orders' => $result[$date]['total_orders'] + $data['total_orders'],
            'total_value' => $result[$date]['total_value'] + $data['total_value'],
        ];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [2020-09-06] => Array
        (
            [total_stickers] => 41
            [total_orders] => 29
            [total_value] => 175.57
        )

    [2020-09-07] => Array
        (
            [total_stickers] => 40
            [total_orders] => 28
            [total_value] => 145.85
        )

)
```

https://3v4l.org/qQ04D

---

Original answer: Sum all marketplaces.

```
<?php
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $date => $marketplaces) {
    foreach ($marketplaces as $marketplace => $data) {
        if (!isset($result[$marketplace])) {
            $result[$marketplace] = $data;
        } else {
            $result[$marketplace] = [
                'total_stickers' => $result[$marketplace]['total_stickers'] + $data['total_stickers'],
                'total_orders' => $result[$marketplace]['total_orders'] + $data['total_orders'],
                'total_value' => $result[$marketplace]['total_value'] + $data['total_value'],
            ];
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [Etsy] => Array
        (
            [total_stickers] => 11
            [total_orders] => 6
            [total_value] => 42.75
        )

    [Woo] => Array
        (
            [total_stickers] => 29
            [total_orders] => 13
            [total_value] => 153.28
        )

    [eBay] => Array
        (
            [total_stickers] => 41
            [total_orders] => 38
            [total_value] => 125.39
        )

)
```

https://3v4l.org/g4CmZ

Comment: see edit, hope it helps, btw $result['2020-09-06']['total_value'] sums up to `175.57` not `175.5`.. I had to pull out google calc to check